# vibrations in front end when slowing down from high speed

Tags: vibration

I have a 2010 mercury mariner. When I'm slowing down to stop I feel a vibration in the front of my vehicle. Only does it at higher speeds.

Comment: Do you notice it most under light braking or heavy braking? Or just rolling to a stop?

Answer (score 3):

The most likely source is that the wheel bearings need adjusting.

Otherwise it may be one or more suspension joints.

A warped brake disc is a possibilty as well.

The cause needs finding and correcting.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosis will likely be by ruling out other causes. Checking your tires is the first step, and one that anyone can do to an extent.  Look for uneven wear.  If it is uneven, there is a likelihood that the tires are out of balance, and a tire can re-balance your tires.  Spin balancing the tires with a computerized spin balancer is the industry standard, and the balancer helps the mechanic do a good job.

Your next most probably step is to look for front end wear.  This is often in the form of tie-rod end wear and ball joint wear, but it can also be brought about by wear of rubber parts (eg: control arms) and wear of shocks and struts and associated bearings and mounts.  For most people, this is done by a mechanic.

Around here, many tire stores with alignment shops offer "courtesy inspections" where they will look for tie/rod and ball joint wear, along with a quick alignment check.

Sometimes vibrations like these can be tough to track down because there are many different things which can contribute to the vibration.  Suspension parts, like front struts are suspect, as well, but they tend to not be the primary reason of the vibration.

Finally, unless your axle on your front end has gotten way under-torqued (rare, and happens when someone does not replace the half-shaft correctly), there are no adjustments for your front wheel bearings.  They are permanently sealed bearings which are pressed into a spindle on the outside, and into a wheel hub on the inside.  If your bearing were problematic, it would be visible upon inspection by a mechanic (with the tire lifted up), and it might cause handing problems or noise.

Oh, the comment about braking by @kyle_engineer is an important diagnostic question, as it is good to know if a loading change affects the vibration.  I would expand his question from light/heavy braking vs coasting to a stop to also include whether the symptoms are identical when turning left or right at a turn a little more aggressive than than an interstate turn.

So in summary, look at your tires.  Even wear, or patterned wear.  Test left to right and with varied braking.  Call around and see if one of the tire shops near you has "courtesy inspections" of the front end.  If they find a problem you can have them fix it if you wish, or take it someplace else.  The nice thing about the courtesy inspection is that there is no obligation, and you can decide in the end what you want to do.